# Pass data by adding the provider in the @component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass data in a new way for me by using providers directly in the component see example, I want to know if it was possible to pass a variable from a component to another without using routing or any other way to do it.

How can I get the variable here? does the variable always have to be static to pass it? I don't want it to be static

**one.component.ts**

```
public toto:string = 'pass this data to two component'
```

**two.component.ts**

```
@component({
 selector : 'app-two-component',
 templateUrl: './two.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./two.component.css'],
 provider: [Onecomponent] // inject OneComponent here
})

export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {

 consructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out services? You use them to store all these data etc and use them where you want it (you should add it as a provider in app module). https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: Yes I know we can use the services to do this but I want to know if this way can work?

Comment: If you need global state, you should use a service. If you are you looking for the `@Input()` decorator to pass some value from a parent-component to the child-component, see the example: https://angular.io/api/core/Input#usage-notes. Both approaches are valid and have their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: If you need to access a component instance of (oneComponent) which is child of TwoComponent, then use ViewChild. If it is other way round, pass through properties using Input. If both of them are unrelated, then use service.

Anything other than this will create confusion to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use services in the providers. From the official docs

https://angular.io/guide/providers

In your case,a sample service might look like the following. Depending on where you provide your services, you can decide on the "scope" of these variables.

oneComponent.service.ts

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class oneComponentService {

  toto:string ;

}
```

two.component.ts

```html
@component({
 selector : 'app-two-component',
 templateUrl: './two.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./two.component.css'],
 provider: [oneComponentService] // inject OneComponent here
})

export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {

 consructor(private oneComponent: oneComponentService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
 // get ref to your variables here
  console.log("oneComponent", this.oneComponent.toto);
 }
}
```